# Hangfire is working OK with local sql db, but not with Azure SQL DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

Hangfire is working OK with local SQL db and MVC.NET , however after azure deployment ( app service + azure SQL db ), its not working anymore.

The recurring job , which was working locally , is not working in azure.

I debugged local code with azure SQL database : does not work. 
Changed connection string to point to local db : Works OK.

Now, I have so many questions like What's wrong with Azure SQL DB ? Is Hangfire a bad choice for production ? What are other alternatives ?

Regardless, as I am so much impressed with Hangfire because of the way it worked locally , if possible,I would like to stick with it to production too.

I don't see any error messages. Do you know how to troubleshoot or why Hangfire is not working with azure SQL db?

Comment: I've used Hangfire in an on-premises network, on the cloud my opinion is it just makes sense to start using Azure Functions